# load data on scroll and update at top if new record added to database in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have the following files of my project.
Just want to add 1 more feature to it using ajax.

i am displaying the database records in descending order and on scroll the data gets loaded,,, if new record is added to database the list should get updated using ajax without  reloading the page,, n new record should get appended at top.

Can anyone help me out or any reference please.
Thanks in advance.

config.php

```
<?php
$db_username    = 'root';
$db_password    = 'root';
$db_name        = 'mydb_demo';
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$items_per_group = 10;
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
?>
```

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Auto Loading Records</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<?php
include("config.php");
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as t_records FROM paginate");
$total_records = $results->fetch_object();
$total_groups = ceil($total_records->t_records/$items_per_group);
$results->close(); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

    $('#results').load("autoload_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;});        //load first group

    $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
        {

            if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
            {
                loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                    $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    track_load++; //loaded group increment
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
body,td,th {font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;font-size: 15px;}
.animation_image {background: #F9FFFF;border: 1px solid #E1FFFF;padding: 10px;width: 500px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;}
#results{width: 500px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;}
#resultst ol{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
#results li{margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px dotted #E1FFFF;padding-top: 20px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<ol id="results">
</ol>
<div class="animation_image" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

autoload_process.php

```
<?php
include("config.php"); //include config file

if($_POST)
{
    //sanitize post value
    $group_number = filter_var($_POST["group_no"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //throw HTTP error if group number is not valid
    if(!is_numeric($group_number)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid number!');
        exit();
    }

    //get current starting point of records
    $position =($group_number * $items_per_group);



    //Limit our results within a specified range. 
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name,message FROM paginate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position, $items_per_group");

    if ($results) { 
        //output results from database

        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<li id="item_'.$obj->id.'">'.$obj->id.' - <strong>'.$obj->name.'</strong></span> &mdash; <span class="page_message">'.$obj->message.'</span></li>';
        }

    }
    unset($obj);
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add some functionality which will keep an eye on change. i will recommend the long polling method. you can find a simple tutorial on it from here

http://webcooker.net/ajax-polling-requests-php-jquery/

and for showing data on the top you should change

```
`$("#results").append(data);`
```

to

```
`$("#results").prepend(data);`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference.. this is what i was searching for since long,,,